# Setting the developerConnection for the Maven Release Plugin from the command line

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I am currently trying to configure the Maven Release Plugin for our build server.

For that I am trying to set the `<scm><developerConnection>` through the command line. I read that

```
project.scm.developerConnection
```

is the command line property(https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html). I tried to set it but it seems to have no effect. When I start the build, it uses a constructed URL (parent pom url + artifactId) that fails.

I have looked at the source code of the plugin but did not find the command line property mentioned above.

Can anybody shed light on this?

Comment: Please show the command line.

Comment: I used `mvn release:prepare -Dproject.scm.developerConnection=...`

Answer (score 4):

It looks that you cannot pass this property directly from command line. See:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-707

But you should get it working by specifying it through a custom property in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <my.developer.connection />
</properties>

<scm>
    <developerConnection>${my.developer.connection}</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

And running maven with, for example:

```
-Dmy.developer.connection=scm:git:ssh://user@host/repo.git
```

I use this approach to keep my pom.xml clean when generating a public release that should not contain information about my company's internals.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `mvn release:prepare`, Maven forks. The arguments supplied on the command line are passed to the initial Maven call (the one you/build server ran) not to the fork.

To pass args to the release plugin, supply the [arguments](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments) as shown:

```
mvn release:prepare -Darguments="-Dproject.scm.developerConnection=..." ...
```

Depending on what I'm trying to do, sometimes I've had to specify in two places, so both original and forked processes get the args:

```
mvn release:prepare -DsomeArg=val -Darguments="-DsomeArg=val" ...
```

The first example in the [release plugin FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/faq.html) shows an example of where the latter is useful.

---- Update ----

I found the property in the [maven-scm-plugin code](https://github.com/apache/maven-scm/blob/1c69683cc876bce8fe1d3af7eea8204dc765b990/maven-scm-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/scm/plugin/ValidateMojo.java).

[image: SCM ValidateMojo.scmDeveloperConnection]

Maybe `project.scm.developerConnection` is read-only? Try setting `scmDeveloperConnection` instead, as it's listed as the property name.

Comment: Thank you, but no luck so far.

Comment: Have you tried running with debug (`-X`)? Might need to specify it in two places. Maybe that will give a clue.

Comment: Yes, but did not see anything. Still confused about this issue.

Comment: Tried this as well, also with a new project, but no luck. Also tried to change `tagBase`, but this only changes the destination, not the source, so it does not work either.

Comment: Thank you so much for the -Darguments suggestion! Azure pipeline required it to be annotated like that for some reason